# Bootstrap modal does not closes on clicking other than the default close button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal on a page and the problem is when the window is maximized, the modal does not closes on clicking outside the modal. But the modal closes when the window is minimized to the possible minimum(with respect to width).

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success bt-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Show</span></button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="true" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Choose a membership that suits you</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- content ------- -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it to close on clicking outside the modal on all times.
I have tried adding **"hide class"** and setting **"data-backdrop to true or static"** but to no success.

I am using bootstrap 2.3.2 . I'll be happy to get any solution remaining in this version of bootstrap.
Here is a link to download this version...
[Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://bootstrap-ru.com/211/)

Comment: How about this? http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_backdrop&stacked=h